# In google app scripts, how would I make a function that subtracts all the cells in one column from all the respective cells in another column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column 'Amount' and a column 'Shipping'. The amount is the total cost of the item including shipping costs. I am trying to subtract the shipping cost from the amount to see what the actual cost of the item was. I would like the output to be in another column on another spreadsheet called 'sheet_destination'. The original values are from 'sheet_origin1'. Here is the function I have so far. I am getting an error when I run the script at the last line that says "TypeError: Cannot read property '172' of undefined". The '172' refers to the last line of sheet_origin1, however I dont know what I am doing wrong here.

```
    var amount = sheet_origin1.getRange(3, 7, sheet_origin1.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
    
    var shipping = sheet_origin1.getRange(3, 10, sheet_origin1.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
    var grossWixTotal = 0;
    for (var g=0; g<amount.length; g++) {
        for (var h=0; h<shipping.length; h++) {
            grossWixTotal = amount[g][h] - shipping[g][h];
        }
    }
sheet_destination.getRange(sheet_destination.getLastRow(), 4, sheet_origin1.getLastRow(), 1).setValues(grossWixTotal[g][h]);
```

Comment: Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You say you have an error in the last line and all of the variables involved in this error have been defined in previous lines that you don't show here. Also a screenshot of your sheet or the actual sheet could be quite useful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

```
function cequalsAminusB() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sr=2;
  const rg=sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,3);
  const v=rg.getValues();
  let o=v.map(r=>{r[2]=r[0]-r[1];return r;});
  rg.setValues(o);
}
```

Initial Data:

```
A,B,C=A-B
1,0.5,
2,0.6,
3,0.7,
4,0.8,
5,0.9,
6,1,
7,1.1,
8,1.2,
9,1.3,
10,1.4,
11,1.5,
12,1.6,
13,1.7,
14,1.8,
15,1.9,
16,2,
17,2.1,
18,2.2,
19,2.3,
```

Starting Spreadsheet:

[image]

Ending Spreadsheet:

[image]

Output just column C:

```
function cequalsAminusB() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sr=2;
  const rg=sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,3);
  const v=rg.getValues();
  let o=v.map(r=>{r[2]=r[0]-r[1];return [r[2]];});
  sh.getRange(sr,3,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Comment: yes this works! But do you know how to just output the 'C' column, and not all the columns? I'm trying to just show the total column in a new spreadsheet

Comment: You just have to remap the output.  You should really learn how to use the array map method.  I included an additional example

Comment: thank you! yes the array map method is very useful.